# How to query database to get value from current_user

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables that look like this

```
class Users(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    expert = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    projects = db.relationship('Projects', backref='author', lazy=True)
    tickets = db.relationship('Tickets',backref='author',lazy=True)

class Tickets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    ticket_text = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow)
    status = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    created_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
```

How to query the database to get all the `Tickets` that assigned to `current_user`?
I did something like this but it doesn't return anything

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    projects = Projects.query.all()
    tickets = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.expert_id == current_user.id).all()
    return render_template('home.html', projects = projects , tickets = tickets)
```

However, If I do

```
tickets = Tickets.query.all()
```

I can successfully get all the tickets that in database

Comment: Is there a reason `current_user.tickets` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @noslenkwah because that doesn't return anything as well, that's why I thought it doesn't work that way and tried query the database

Answer (score 0):

As your shared code seems incomplete, can you revalidate the following?

1. Value of current_user
2. Is there any data actually associated with current_user.id in Tickets table.
3. Is it actually maintaining relationship for expert_id with users table?

Please share above information if possible, then it would be easier to figure out the issue if there are some.

Comment: 1. The value of the current_user is a user that logged in using Flask-Login 2. Each ticket has user that those tickets assigned to. I did this by created expert_id on Tickets table 3.Yes it is because Tickets has user.id that works as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance that for this API route, current user is not set.
You can confirm it by using current_user.is_authenticated.

If user is set, and you're getting the user value ie Id then check at db, whether data is there not for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `current_user`, then you can use the variable `tickets` in the `User` model to get all the tickets that belong to the `current_user`.

Your `index()` view function will look like this:

```py
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    all_tickets = current_user.tickets.all()
    return render_template('home.html', all_tickets=all_tickets)
```